# Can free plagiarism tools cause plagiarism false positives when students upload content checked with free tools to Turnitin?

Tags: citations, plagiarism, software

As a lecturer, I have advised many students to use a free plagiarism checker tool to verify their work is plagiarism free, when they don't have access to a widely-used paid tool like Turnitin. I encountered a questionable issue related to this in a discussion today. My question concern the following scenario:

When students do not have access to Turnitin, they can use any free plagiarism tool. Then they upload a small document (below 1000 word document) or they copy and paste the text and check for plagiarism using any free plagiarism checker. (I do not mention names here, most of the free versions allow only 1000 words.) When students upload their whole document to the university portal (UK universities Canvas or Blackboard), it will automatically check with Turnitin if the portal is supporting Turnitin access for student uploads. In this scenario, will it be shown as plagiarized or not genuine work, since part of the document or the whole document of the student has been uploaded in free tools? (In case the free plagiarism tool has stored the text - I do not know whether the free tools are capable of that or not - this work just like the way Turnitin works with student repository.)

Can the scenario I mentioned above happen?

Comment: If students really write their own stuff, why in the world should they "check for plagiarism" at all?

Comment: If it does then turnitin is seriously broken. (Which may be true anyway.)

Comment: @paulgarrett Agree with you. but incase they have missed to cite properly they will get caught for plagiarism right? (This can be identified using a free tool, correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Buffy is there a possibility?

Comment: I solved this problem by giving my students access to view their own Turnitin results. That was primarily a moral decision based on the premise that no evaluation of student work should be secret from the students. Of course, if they plagiarize, they'll be able to see what I see, too.

Comment: @BobBrown In my case students don't have Turnitin access from the very beginning. One week before the deadline they get Turnitin access, that's why I have asked students to check plagiarism with free plagiarism checkers till they get Turnitin access. By the time they get turnitin access, they can upload and they can view their own plagiarism report by accessing Turnitin studio. But my concern is will the students' work be shown as plagiarised content when they submit it to Turnitin as they already have uploaded those documents or parts of those documents for free plagiarism checkers.

Comment: 'I have asked students to check plagiarism with free plagiarism checkers'  Have you read the terms and conditions of those free plagiarism checkers, and are you sure you want to expose your students to those terms and conditions?

Comment: The Turnitin report should tell you from what source(s) it has detected plagiarism.  That will be a good start in finding out the answer to your question.  In general, a high Turnitin score on its own should not be the basis of a formal charge of plagiarism, only the trigger to _begin_ a human-led investigation to find out whether there really are grounds to suspect plagiarism.

Comment: @DanielHatton Until I read your comments, I didn't pay much attention to that. I just checked a policy of one site which the students refer to, *https://plagiarismdetector.net/privacy* 
"User Content to Check Plagiarism

Comment: @DanielHatton Continuing from previous comment 
We do not save or store the user content uploaded for checking plagiarism. Neither do we share the user content with any third party. The confidentiality of our users’ documents is a priority for us.
The files or content you upload for the detection of plagiarism is immediately removed from our system after processing.
The content or files uploaded by users are not indexed by any search engine."

If this has been implemented, there won't be any issues like I have mentioned in my post right?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it would be "possible". It just depends on the systems. If the free tool has stored or published the content anywhere where it can be seen by other systems, then it's going to be a possibility. As has been said, the terms and conditions of any tools should be checked prior to using them to identify if the content is going to be used in any way.